# SAT question - Random Sample/Population

Tags: statistics

I'm tutoring a student in preparation for the SAT. Below is a question that I think has two good answers - both A and D. However, D is the official answer. If D is indeed the best answer here, would someone please explain why.

In particular, it reads as if option A is a subset of option D, and if the newspaper showed bias (i.e. political bias) then should not A be the answer?
[image]

Comment: What is answer E?!!?!!  Is that really an answer they listed on the exam?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They polled from the list of all voters, not from the newspaper readers.  Therefore D is the only correct answer.